# Why in SELECT query syntax as use ID = '140qwe4' it is treated ID like '140'

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a SQL syntax:

```html
SELECT * FROM matches LEFT JOIN 
predictions ON matches.matchid = predictions.matchid 
and predictions.userid = '8' 
where matches.matchid = '140qwe4'
```

SQL returns me result where matches.matchid = 140. I`m looking not for this ID. Can someone explain why . Example below:
[SQL query and result from DB.JPG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzq5L.png)

Answer (score 2):

MySQL does implicit conversion of strings to numbers in a numeric context.

It does so by converting the leading "digits" (including `-` and `.`) to a number.  So `matchid` is a number.  `'140qwe4'` is a string.  The rules of type conversion specify that the comparison is made as a number (not a string).  The string is converted to a number.  Hence, `140`.

Do not mix types in your SQL queries.  It can result in unexpected results.  It can also impede the optimizer.

The rules for type conversion are described [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/type-conversion.html).

Comment: He could cast : ... `CAST(matches.matchid AS CHAR)` ... ?

Comment: @flourPower . . . Although that is possible, it prevents the optimizer from using an index.  And, it is rather ridiculous.  If `matchid` is a number, it should be compared to a number.